# Open download windows using jQuery's each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I've got a table containing several rows where each row represents an exportable file, e. g.:

```
<tr>
  <th class="text-center" scope="row">
    <input id="exportID-23" type="checkbox" />
  </th>
  <td class="text-center text-nowrap">2016-08-24</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>City</td>
  <td class="text-center text-nowrap">Person</td>
</tr>
[...]
<button id="exports" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> Export
</button>
```

In order to return only those files requested upon the user's click on the export button, I wrote this:

```js
$('#exports').click(function () {
  var exports = $(this);

  $('[id^=exportID-]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      window.open('ajax/get-exports.php?ExportID=' + this.id.substring(9));
    }
  });
});
```

Now, debugging my code using Firefox's developer console, `each()` works as expected: I get a new window for each download.
However, running the same code without the debugger, it only opens a new window for the last selected row.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer to this problem - neither here on SO nor elsewhere in the depths of the Internet, so: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having the developer console opened and executing your code often elimates caching issue. Can you please do a CTRL+SHIFT+DEL and clear  your cache and try executing your code without the dev console opened.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @DavidR! It was indeed a caching issue.
If you add your comment as an answer, I'd happily accept it as such. :)

Comment: Already done! :)  
Sorry for the wrong mentioning, but SO seems to struggle with usernames containing spaces - I've clicked the auto completion several times, but upon saving, it doesn't turn into a clickable text. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the developer console opened and executing your code often eliminates caching issue. Can you please do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> and clear your cache and try executing your code without the developer console opened.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> To open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special value _blank for strWindowName.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open (end of the first paragraph of examples section)